# Calculate stock duration from today

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet which shows me the inventory of my stock.

```
Product name      Qty       Average orders/month      Stock available until:
Product1          100            10                           xx/xx/xxxx
```

I would like to calculate, using today date, the estimated date my stock will be at 0.

In this example I have 100 / 10 = 10 month from today.But how can I get the date difference? ie convert 10 months from now into a date

Also I know how to change background color according to specific values of the cell, but how can I do the same for the amount of days between today and the estimated date?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a look at the EOMONTH function.  I am assuming you dont really care about the day of the month since its average sales in the month which means some dales could be happening on the very last day.

Comment: Actually I care. These averages are very precise and I want to put a red background when we are 21 days from the stock empty estimated date. So end of month wouldn't fit in my case.

Comment: so what day of the month do the average sales occur on?

Comment: not any particular day, it depends on the marketing actions. So if we take the example above, I know that right now I have 10 month of stock exactly, so I would like to add 10 months (or the result of the calculation) to todays date. If we have 10.5, then it would add 10 month and a half. etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=date(year(today()),month(today())+10,day(today())
```

The above formula we put you on the same calendar date that is 10 months after the current month.  The number of days between today and that day 10 months from now will vary as the number of days in a month changes.  You will also get some slightly unexpected results when you try to find the 30th day 10 months from April since February only has 28/29 days.  it will actually tell you early march which is technically 11 months away.

Where you see 10 in the formula above, replace it with your equation that will calculate 10

Since you will be dealing with fractions of a month, you will need to determine a way that suits your needs to convert that into number of days.  My personal recommendation is you treat every month as having 30 days.  so 10.5 months is really 10.5*30=315 days.  So the formula above would become:

```
=today()+315
or
=today()+10.5*30
```

So in this case replace either the 10.5 with your formula that calculates months or replaces 315 with your formula that converts fractions of a month into days.  Note days will need to be an integer so consider rounding your results `ROUND(results,0)` or `INT(results)`.

As for changing your cell colour based on conditional formatting, lets assume your end date is in the D column.  Select the range in the D column making sure your active cell is D2 (by default this would be the cell with the white background and is the first cell clicked on to start the last selection drag).  Go into your conditional formatting and select formula ando for your logicinal condition to return true you and have the colouring take effect you want to use a formula like:

```
=D2-today()<=21
```

That should evaluate true or false.

Comment: Thank you, it works when the calculation returns an integer, but in case of a float like 10.5 months, I get the same result as 10. That's where my biggest problem is^^ and that's why I post here :) it would be possible to add 30xresult to the days, but if you have a more precise solution I'd take it

Comment: I saw the 10.5 come up in a follow up comment but it was not part of your original question.  Since .5 of a month will vary in terms of number of days in the future depending on the month some have 28 days others 31, I would recommend you treat every month as having 30 days regardless of what month it is.  Convert you month from 10.5 to 315 days and add that to the day part of the function instead of adding 10 to the month part.

Comment: thanks anyway, it will already give me some useful results. Do you have an idea for the background color change ? I go to conditional formatting, create a new rule using a formula... it would be something like current_cell - TODAY() >15 but how do I type to use the current cell from the selected column?

Comment: actually I ran into another problem, if the amount of days to add goes above the end of the month, it displays the wrong date... it doesn't increment month/year

Comment: Updated the increasing the date formula by X number of days as well as conditional formatting option

Comment: yes! I've found the same thing on my side, it was the easy option actually :) thanks for your help